# Leaflet and heatmaps: I can't read data from json files

Tags: jquery, json, leaflet, heatmap

I am following a tutorial to generate a heat map using leaflet and heatmap.js. The tutorial works well, but when I try to read data from a file it stops working. At the moment, I am trying with small data set but the data set will increase in the future. Please, could someone help me to fix it.

```
var testData = {
  max: 8,
  data : $.getJSON("js/ozone2.json", function(data){})
};
```

`console.log(testData);`

```
var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',{
attribution: "thank you",
id: 'mapbox.streets',
accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpa2FoZCIsImEiOiJjamRnMjY0cnUwY2hrMnBwaGdzZDl4OGpuIn0.t3JrTRNTPesh-gTCjAg4_w',
});

var configuration = {
"radius": 20,
"maxOpacity": 0.5,
"scaleRadius": false,
"useLocalExtrema": true,
latField: 'lat',
lngField: 'lng',
valueField: 'value'
};

var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(configuration);

var map =  new L.map('map', { 
center: new L.latLng(53.1424, -7.6921),
zoom: 8,
minZoom: 3,
maxZoom: 14,
ZoomControl: false,
layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
});

heatmapLayer.setData(testData);
heatmapLayer.addTo(map);
layer=heatmapLayer;
```

Data in json file:

```
[
 {"lat":"58.75", "lng":"18.5", "value": "50"},
 {"lat":"59.0", "lng":"18.5", "value": "50"}
]
```

Comment: I think you should add your 'heatmapLayer' to the map and set it's data inside the `getJSON`  `function(data)`. [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) is a very convinient plugin to create geojson featuregroups async.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. My getJSON() function was incorrect. it didn't return a value.